# Relation between Moore-penrose pseudoinverse and $A^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, nonlinear-optimization

I have the following question:

If $Ax=b$ where $A \in R^{m \times n}$, then we can get $x = A'b$ where $A'$ is the moore-pensrose psuedoinverse. Is it true that $x$ is unique if $x^Ty = 0 \forall y \in N(A)$ and $$x \in R(A^T) = N^{\perp}(A)?$$

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I haven't tried to parse your formula, but here is another picture showing what the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse does. Here's a geometric description: The input to the pseudoinverse is  a vector in the codomain. Project it orthogonally to the image, i.e., to point closest to it in the image. Pick any vector in the preimage of the projected point and project it orthogonally onto the orthogonal complement of the kernel. This is independent of which vector you chose in the preimage. That's the output of the pseudoinverse.

Comment: What do you mean by "$x$ is unique?" - i.e. $x$ is the unique vector satisfying $A' b = x$?

Answer (score 1):

The relation between the spaces is given by:

[image]

What you can say is if $ \boldsymbol{b} \in \mathcal{R} \left( \boldsymbol{A} \right) $ then there is a solution to the equation.

All solution will be in the form $ \boldsymbol{x}_{r} + \boldsymbol{x}_{n} $ where $ \boldsymbol{x}_{r} \in \mathcal{R} \left( \boldsymbol{A}^{T} \right) $ and $ \boldsymbol{x}_{n} \in \mathcal{N} \left( \boldsymbol{A} \right) $.

The only way for this set of solution to be a singleton is in case the null space is empty.

What can be shown is that the *Pseudo Inverse* using the SVD gives the least norm solution. Namely it gives back $ \boldsymbol{x}_{r} $.

Here is a sketch of a proof for that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to parse your formula, but here is [another picture](https://deaneyang.github.io/blog/blog/math/linear-algebra/matrix/moore-penrose/2022/12/16/MoorePenrose.html) showing what the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse does.

Here's a verbal description: The input to the pseudoinverse is a vector $y$ in the codomain. Project it orthogonally to the image, i.e., to the point $\bar{y}$ closest to $y$ in the image. Pick any vector $\bar{x}$ in the preimage of $\bar{y}$ and project it onto the orthogonal complement of the kernel. The resulting vector (labeled $L^+(y)$ in the picture, which does not depend on which vector you chose in the preimage, is the output of the pseudoinverse.